# URL rewrite using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the URL using the mod_rewrite apache module.
I am trying to use it as below :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wants/testing.htm wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```

I have created a .htaccess file in the directory from where the files are accessed.

The mod_rewrite is also enabled.
With all these done, i still haven't been able to get it working.

Can someone please help me with this? Please let me know if i am missing something

Thanks in Advance,
Gnanesh

Comment: What exactly is not working for you ? How do you expect the URL to be rewritten and where dou you want to extract the wantid parameter from ?

Comment: The URL shows mydomain.com/wants.php?wantid=123.
I need to make it look like mydomain.com/wants/123

Comment: $1 is the reference to the $_GET parameter,wantid in the URL. Please let me know if i am not clear enough.

I am new to URL rewrite

Answer (score 2):

As per OP's comment:

> The URL shows
>   mydomain.com/wants.php?wantid=123. I
>   need to make it look like
>   mydomain.com/wants/123

This should work for your case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wants/([0-9]+)$ /wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```

It will allow you to use **http://yoursite.com/wants/123** and will silently rewrite it to **wants.php?wantid=123**

Answer (score 0):

I think a leading slash (or rather the lack thereof) might be yoru problem:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wants/testing.htm /wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```

Otherwise Apache might be looking for the PHP file in /wants/wants.php as it'll be treating it as a relative URL.

Comment: ^/wants/testing.htm /wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]

Comment: @SpliFF no, that's for .conf files not .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, so I gave it some thought and I guess you could do something like this ( only changed the regexp according to your comment, if I understood correctly ):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wants/\d+$ /wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```

But I guess you could also leave out the $1 reference, and still be able to access the id in your `wants.php`. So

```
RewriteRule ^wants/\d+$ /wants.php [L]
```

should work too, and you can then use something like

```
<?php 
    $request = split('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[1];
?>
```

in your `wants.php` where the last element of the array would be your id ( or anything else you ever decide to rewrite and send to the script ).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the rule in the .htaccess file in your *wants* directory, you have to strip the contextual `wants/` from the start of the pattern. So just:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, if you want to use the rule in the .htaccess file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wants/([0-9]+)$ wants.php?wantid=$1 [L]
```